# Wrong spacing of circled numbers using Tikz and exam class

Tags: tikz-pgf, exam

1. I am using XeLaTex.
2. I am also using the package `exam`.
3. I am preparing a multiple choice test, but I have no Scantron and I want students to tick the desired **circled** answer by pen.
4. This is the relevant part of my preamble in which I have set up the command `\circled{}` to obtain the desired formatting of answers:

   ```
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
       \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
   \renewcommand\choicelabel{\circled{\thechoice}}
   \renewcommand\thechoice{\arabic{choice}}%
   ```
5. And this is the typical structure of a multiple choice question

   ```
   \question Choose among the following
   \begin{oneparchoices}
   \choice wrong answer;
   \choice sounds-good-but-it-is-not answer;
   \choice right answer.
   \end{oneparchoices}
   ```
6. The PDF output is
   [image]
7. *I do not like the spacing that precedes the circled number*. So far, I have found no simple solution to this issue. Ideally, I would like to get the usual spacing between the preceding word and the circled number.

Comment: Off-topic: Why not just `\textcircle{\thechoice}`? TiKZ seems like overkill!

Answer (score 2):

You can patch the oneparchoices like

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}
                          {\penalty -50\hskip 0.4em plus 0.25em\relax}  %% change here as you like
                          {}
                          {}
```

Change the values as you like.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand\choicelabel{\circled{\thechoice}}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\arabic{choice}}%
%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}
                          {\penalty -50\hskip 0.4em plus 0.25em\relax}  %% change here as you like
                          {}
                          {}
\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Choose among the following
      \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice wrong answer;
        \choice sounds-good-but-it-is-not answer;
        \choice right answer.

     \end{oneparchoices}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With just `\space` in

```
\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}
                          {\space}  %% change here as you like
                          {}
                          {}
```

you get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedbacks... now my document is perfect!

Comment: Just for the record, `textcircled{}` produces a really ugly output.

Comment: @Valerio: For your reference: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)