# Width of columns with circled numbers in a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I think my question is similar to this one: [Wrong spacing of circled numbers using Tikz and exam class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213715/wrong-spacing-of-circled-numbers-using-tikz-and-exam-class#)
but I'm not quite sure.

In a talk using the `beamer` class I used a table and it involved `tikz` circled numbers as I saw in an answer here.

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.1pt] (char) {#1};}}
```

The table looked like this:
[image]

As you can see the width of the columns with circled numbers is different from the columns that don't have them. The code is

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccccc}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&2&3&4&5&&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&2&3&4&5&&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&2&3&4&5\\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{7-7} \cline{13-13}
    2 &\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&2&\circled{2}&3&&2&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&2&3&\circled{3}&&2&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&2&3&\circled{3}\\
    \cline{2-2} \cline{8-8} \cline{14-14}
    3&3&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&\circled{1}&2&&3&3&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&2&\circled{2}&&3&3&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&\circled{1}&2\\
    \cline{3-3} \cline{9-9} \cline{15-15}
    4&4&4&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{3}&4&&4&4&4&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&4&&4&4&4&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{2}&4\\
    \cline{4-4} \cline{10-10} \cline{16-16}
    5&5&5&5&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&&5&5&5&5&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}&&5&5&5&5&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{1}\\
    \cline{5-5} \cline{11-11} \cline{17-17}
\end{tabular}
```

It would have been preferable to have all columns the same width. How could I have done that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming every column has at least one non-circled number you could use

```
\mycircled{1}
```

defined via

```
\newcommand\mycircled[1]{\makebox[0pt]{\circled{#1}}}
```

Which hides the width of the circled entries.

Otherwise you could replace 0pt by `\digitwidth` defined by

```
\newlength\digitwidth
\settowidth\digitwidth{1}
```

To force a circled digit to be as wide as a plain 1.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. It didn't at first because apparently you can't define it in presentation mode. When I moved it to the top and added some curly braces it worked.

Comment: @MattSamuel I have no idea what "presentation mode is" (something in your editor?) but glad it works anyway:-) (I just added the missing `}`, sorry)